# iOS6 - Facebook V3 SDK VS Apple Facebook iOS6 SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk, ios6

If I'm targetting my app only for iOS6 can I handle all my Facebook "business" with the new Facebook SDK included with iOS6 or do I need to also use Facebook V3 SDK?